# Extraneous character while converting string to buffer and back in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node v16.14.2,

```
> String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Buffer.from('°'))
'Â°'
```

This works fine though:

```
> Buffer.from('°').toString('utf-8')
'°'
```

I want to know why the first scenario adds an extra character in the output.

Browser example:

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from('°'))) /// 'Â°'
console.log(ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from('°').toString('utf-8')) // '°'
console.log(new Uint8Array(ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from('°'))) // [ 194, 176 ]
console.log(new Uint8Array(ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(176)))) // [ 194, 176 ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereumjs/browser-builds/dist/ethereumjs-tx/ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**:
Another funny thing:

```
> new Uint8Array(Buffer.from('°'))
Uint8Array(2) [ 194, 176 ]
> new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(176)))
Uint8Array(2) [ 194, 176 ]
```

Comment: _The static String.fromCharCode() method returns a string created from the specified sequence of UTF-16 code units._

Comment: The code unit of '°' is 176. I do not know the implementation details of UTF-16, but it should have same code unit value for both UTF-8 and UTF-16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default string encoding of `Buffer.from` is UTF-8 which encodes characters in the Extended ASCII range using two bytes. (It can't just use one byte because the highest order bit of that byte is used to signal multibyte encoding.)

UTF-8 two-byte encoding has the form:

`110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`

which gives 11 bits to represent a character code.

The ASCII code of `'°'` is 176

```bash
> '°'.charCodeAt(0)
176
```

which in binary is:

```bash
> (176).toString(2)
'10110000'
```

So replacing the x with this binary value we have:

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
110xxx10 10110000
      ^^   ^^^^^^
```

which means the UTF-8 two-byte encoding of `'°'` is

`11000010 10110000`

or

`194 176`

as expected:

```bash
> [...Buffer.from('°')]
[ 194, 176 ]

> String.fromCharCode(194)
'Â'

> String.fromCharCode(176)
'°'
```